# angular 5: template binding within table row

Tags: html, angular, angular5

**How do you bind a template containing `td`s within a `tr`?**

I have a table that I want column sections to be dynamically added/removed/rearranged.

My `td`s are grouped into categories, the user can pick categories, and then the sections of the table should be pieced together with if/then logic using the category ids.

I'm having trouble binding my category templates into `tr`. I've tried:

1. setting the component selector to "app-componentName" and inputting the component using `<app-componentName></app-componentName>`
2. setting the component selector to "[app-componentName]" and inputting the component using `<template app-componentName></template>`

but neither works correctly. Using the first option, all of the data from my category is put into one `td`. Using the second option, none of my categories show up at all.

Here's the gist...

**`table-row.component.ts`**

```
...
var selectedCategories = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "billing address"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name"
  }
];
...
```

**`table-row.component.html`**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of selectedCategories">
  <app-name-cells [person]="person" *ngIf="category.id === 1">
  <app-billing-address-cells [person]="person" *ngIf="category.id === 2">
</ng-container>
```

**`name-cells.component.html`**

```
<td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{user.middleName}}</td>
<td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
```

**`billing-address-cells.component.html`**

```
<td>{{user.billingAddress.line1}}</td>
<td>{{user.billingAddress.line2}}</td>
<td>{{user.billingAddress.city}}</td>
<td>{{user.billingAddress.state}}</td>
<td>{{user.billingAddress.zip}}</td>
```

**Result**

```
//full address in first cell, full name in second cell

|| 123 Main St New York NY 12345 | John A Doe ||
```

**Expected Result**

```
// each part of each component in it's own cell

|| 123 Main St | New York | NY | 12345 | John | A | Doe ||
```

## Edit - Added StackBlitz:

See code example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lajpya)

Comment: Much more clear, stackblitz will work good - please do add

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lajpya

Comment: Getting error in stackblitz

Comment: I'm aware of this. I got tired of trying to get it to work. It works in my app, but for some reason, in stackblitz, it's trying to bind the object to the `tr` instead of the `app-table-row` template.

Comment: its fixed. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cm6jqj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: added stackblitz (working now) to initial question